# How can I restore all the queries of MySQL workbench workspace?

Tags: mysql-workbench, restore

I have been making queries since 6 months from now and they were all available when I opened the mysql workbench workspace. Although when I opened mysql wokbench today I received this error messsage.

[image: error message]

I lost all the queries that I made. I cannot restore the workspace. Can you please help? :(
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: they are gone afaik

Comment: Sorry to say it - but they are probably gone - always best practice to save critical work.

Comment: Not all might be lost. Can you navigate to the folder shown in the message? Are there any files left? Also, copy the entire message as text and show it here (press Ctrl+C in the dialog to copy it). I'd like to see which file cannot be opened.

Comment: The message is:
"Could not read contents of 'C:\Users\mcarrilho\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces\dw_user-1.autosave\'.
Failed to open file 'C:\Users\mcarrilho\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces\dw_user-1.autosave\': No such file or directory"

I can navigate to the folder. The folder is not empty. It has many files .info, and .scratch

Answer (score 0):

Try to find your queries in logs here: %APPDATA%\MySQL\Workbench\log\